# Прием пакетов с сервера Minecraft

Tags: java, сеть, tcp, rust, minecraft

Я установил простой сервер майнкрафта последней версии и написал программу на Rust, которая может зайти на этот сервер ([вот алгоритм](https://wiki.vg/Protocol#Login)). Соединение через TCP (через UDP сервер не слушает) Однако у меня возникла проблема с парсингом входящих пакетов. После соединения ко мне приходит в среднем ~6к коротких пакетов за 16 секунд, после чего персонажа выкидывает. Насколько нормально такое количество пакетов? Судя по второму байту - у всех Packet ID равен нулю, что тоже вызывает вопросы.

После захода появляется персонаж, в чат выводится сообщение "BotMichael joined the game".

Вот пример пакетов (одна строка - один пакет):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это я что то делаю не так? Как мне распарсить эти пакеты?

Также, судя по [алгоритму](https://wiki.vg/Protocol#Login), после того, как я отправляю Login Start, должен прийти Encryption Request, у которого Packet ID должен быть равен 1 (второй-четвертый байт, зависит от пакета), однако среди этих пакетов он везде равен нулю.

Comment: на том же wiki.vg есть список библиотек, в которых есть реализация разной версии и степени завершенности этого протокола на самых разных языках, в том числе и расте, можно попробовать подсмотреть там - https://wiki.vg/Library_List

Comment: разобрались с проблемой?